# SMS Conversation

Tags: android, listview

I am developing a SMS application. I am able to send and receive SMS.

I have a tab named "Inbox". When clicking on it, I show all conversations using URI `content://mms-sms/conversations/`.

When clicking any conversation, I want to show all SMS conversations between that person and me.

I have fetched all messages of that person from URI `content://sms/inbox`, 
and my messages to that person from URI `content://sms/sent`.

Now,how can I show these messages in a custom list view so that My messages have prefix "me" and the other person's messages have prefix "< name/number >" and are arranged according to date and time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to do something similar. Did you solve it? I think I should do it manually!
I think use the phone number as login (not all companies store the number on the phone) and then compare the message number with logged number.
On layout you can have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMessageDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:maxWidth="250dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMessageRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/righttext"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:maxWidth="250dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMessageLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lefttext"
        android:maxWidth="250dip"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Whit logged number you can known if the number if from your number or from the other side number, so in code you can inflate the layout and with an "if" you can write your name or the contact name.
Something similar to this:

```
if(o.getOriginatingAddress().equals(MainActivity.loggedNumber))                
    tvOutMessage.setText("me: " + o.getMessageBody());
else
    tvInMessage.setText("contact:" + o.getMessageBody());
```

I don't known if this is the best solution, but hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have solved it. I have gathered sms's from  outbox and inbox with same number and added "me" and <name/number> in strings.